# Message passing between EventMachine connections

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, stomp

I am attempting to write a chat server with EventMachine. How do I pass a message from one EventMachine connection, to another, in a thread-safe manner?

I see a messaging protocol (Stomp) being supported but I can't figure out how to use it. Any help is appreciated.

Stomp in EventMachine - http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Protocols/Stomp.html

Comment: 1. EM Stomp protocol implementation is a Client, not a Server.
2. EM does't have to do anything with Thread (unless you use `defer` for some special cases)

Answer (score 1):

See http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Channel.html

you can try something in these lines:

```
require 'eventmachine'

class Chat < EventMachine::Connection  
  def initialize channel
    @channel = channel
  end

  def post_init
    send_data 'Hello'
    @sid = @channel.subscribe do |msg|
      send_data msg
    end
  end

  def receive_data(msg)
    @channel.push msg
  end

  def unbind
    @channel.unsubscribe @sid
  end
end

EM.run do
  @channel = EventMachine::Channel.new
  EventMachine.start_server '127.0.0.1', 8081, Chat, @channel
end
```

EDIT: also check out https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/tree/master/examples/guides/getting_started - there is a nice chatroom example

Answer (score 0):

Try starting out with an in memory message dispatcher.

```
require 'thread'

class Room
  def initialize
    @users = []
  end

  def join(user)
    @users << user
  end

  def leave(user)
    @user.delete(user)
  end

  def broadcast(message)
    @users.each do |user|
      user.enqueue(message)
    end
  end
end

class User

  def initialize
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    @queued_messages = []
  end

  def enqueue(message)
    @mutex.synchronize do
      @queued_message << message
    end
  end

  def get_new_messages
    @mutex.synchronize do
      output = @queued_messages
      @queued_messages = []
    end
    return output
  end

end
```

**UPDATE**

```
ROOM = Room.new

class Connection
  def user_logged_in
    # @user = ...
    ROOM.join(@user)
  end

  def received_message(message)
    ROOM.broadcast(message)
  end

  def receive_send_more_messages_request(req)
    messages = @user.get_new_messages
    # write messages
  end

  def connection_closed
    ROOM.leave(@user)
  end
end
```

Comment: The logic happens inside EventMachine::Connection objects, and so, how do I get them to wake up and check for a message?